# How can I speed up the mobile dropdown in the Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the mobile phone, there is a dropdown menu on the navbar. But it is far too slow.

Is it JQuery based? Or is it CSS transition based? How do I speed it up?

Comment: do you mean the navbar-collapse?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is CSS transition based, try changing the height value from the transition property of this class.

```
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height .35s ease;
       -o-transition: height .35s ease;
          transition: height .35s ease;
}
```

Comment: It appears only the last three lines are needed. Change the ease values to .01s for instant(ish) drop down animation.

Comment: Or even simpler...

    .collapsing {
        transition-duration: 0s;
    }