# How to improve speed of navbar menu drawer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented a drawer for my cordova app using the navbar component from twitter bootstrap with tweaks from this project https://github.com/adamnurdin01/bootsnav

The end result is this http://algopesa.com/appWire/#

However, the drawer is not drawing as quickly as i would like it to be. Is there a way i can make the menu drawer display quicker?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I speed up the mobile dropdown in the Bootstrap navbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378785/how-can-i-speed-up-the-mobile-dropdown-in-the-bootstrap-navbar)

Comment: I have tried the solution there. The classes involved after inspection seem to be `navbar-collapse collapse in` The question linked suggests class `collapsing`

Comment: Provide code, then we may be able to help you.

Comment: This has worked `.collapse{
  position: relative ;
  height: 0 ;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height .20s ease !important;
       -o-transition: height .20s ease !important;
          transition: height .20s ease !important;
}`